# Link Firebase Accounts which do not have a provider to Microsoft

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to link existing Firebase accounts to Microsoft accounts.

My login inside my iOS app to Microsoft (Azure AD) works correctly, if an account with the same email does not exist yet, but i want to merge existing accounts with those Microsoft accounts.
The reason for this is, that I want to define the UID which the user gets by creating those account prior via Firebase SDK.

The problem seems to be, that these accounts created via Firebase SDK can not be flagged as a "Microsoft" account. Actually they don't get any provider after being created.
And on the other hand the function `Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData(with: pendingCred)` does not seem to work for those accounts which do not have a provider set (please correct me if this is wrong).

Does anyone know a solution to get Microsoft accounts into Firebase authentication with an UID which I can define?

[image: no provider]

Edit: What I have found out so far:

A login with `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)` does merge duplicated accounts with an empty provider automatically (which does make sense).

I would have expected this behaviour too when I use `Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)`, but this is sadly not the case. Maybe someone else knows a solution.

Comment: Firebase supports account linking - have you looked at this? E.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking (iOS) or https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking (web).

Comment: Yes I did. But it looks to me, that the linking only works if there is already an active auth provider which I want to link to. In my case there are only "empty" accounts with no previously used auth provider set.